# Saving meta box data from selected option's value in database is not working

Tags: php, html, sql, wordpress, foreach

I have added a organizer input filed using "select and option" tag, screenshot - https://prnt.sc/DtiJr5W178_g

Here is my full code -

```html
// Callback function for Metabox

function meta_box_content_footer($post){
global $post;
    
?>

<form action="" method="post">
   
    <div class='event-data-content'>
    <div class="contain1" style="width:50%; float:left;">
    
<?php 

// Save Post Meta
add_action('save_post', 'so_save_metabox');

function so_save_metabox(){ 
    global $post;

    if(isset($_POST["custom_element_grid_class"])){
         //UPDATE: 
        $meta_element_class = $_POST['custom_element_grid_class'];
        //END OF UPDATE

        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_box_content_footer', $meta_element_class);

    }

}



// Function for organizer section
function custom_element_grid_class_meta_box($post){
    global $wpdb;
    global $post;
    $meta_element_class = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_element_grid_class_meta_box', true); 
?>   

        <div class="full-area">
        <label  class="label0" for="cars">Organizer:</label>
        <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" id="select-or" multiple="multiple" name="custom_element_grid_class" id="custom_element_grid_class" >

<?php

$organizer_query = "SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='event_organizer' AND post_status='publish'";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($organizer_query);

foreach ($results as $result){

?>
        <option value="" name="custom_element_grid_class">    
            <?php echo $result->post_title ?>
        </option>  
<?php

}
?>
        </select>
        </div>
<?php

var_dump ($post->ID);
}

custom_element_grid_class_meta_box ($post);




// Script for multiselection .....
?>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
});
</script>

    </div>
    </div>
    
    </form>


    <?php
    }
```

I have shown option's value using foreach loop. I have added a custom post type for organizer where admin can add organizer and that values (The title of of the organize's post) are basically being shown as option's value using foreach loop. The problem is those option's values are not being updated or saved in database. Please suggest....
Thanks,
Mani